# Java - why are 2 versions shown?

Tags: java

I would like to know which version of java is installed on my ubuntu system.

The java -version command shows:

**cmdprompt$** java -version

> java version "1.6.0_20"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
> 1.6.0_20-b02)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build
> 16.3-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

However the following cmd **shows 2 Java versions installed? What are these?**

**cmdprompt$** ls -l $(type -path -all java)

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 2010-02-28 14:21 **/usr/bin/java** -> **/etc/alternatives/java**
>
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 2010-06-29 22:36 **/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java** ->
> **../jre/bin/java**

**How do I ensure there is ONLY ONE version of JAVA is installed - so that there are no build conflicts?**

Comment: AFAIK, this has nothing to do with programming. Anyway, the two lines that you got with `ls -l $(type -path -all java)` don't imply that you have two Java versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu supports several different possible installations of Java by a common trick, namely symlinks. If you type `which java` it will tell you that "java" resolves to "/usr/bin/java" (where Java is supposed to be installed), which in turn points to `/etc/alternatives/java` which is a symlink that is automatically updated via the `update-alternatives` command. This command may be used to, for example, switch between Sun's Java implementation and the Open JDK version of Java. There won't be any conflicts, since they each occupy distinct locations and have distinct paths, and the symlink (where the system expects to find Java) may be easily updated to switch to whichever one is to be used.

You can use `update-alternatives` to see which version of Java is currently selected. For example:

```
sudo update-alternatives -l
```

The command above will tell you which "alternatives" have been selected for various tools.

Answer (score 4):

The `alternatives` directory contains links pointing to your preferred alternatives. (This makes it really easy to switch between preferred versions.)

To me it looks like you only have one version installed, and that this version is pointed to by `/etc/alternatives/java`.

> **How do I ensure there is ONLY ONE version of JAVA is installed - so that there are no build conflicts?**

Well, first of all, I doubt that you'll be running into trouble with build-conflicts. But to ensure that you only have one version of java installed, you could list all installed packages called something with java like this:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -i java
```

and then remove the packages you don't want to have installed, using `apt-get remove pkgname`.

Answer (score 1):

I have always had about a dozen version of java installed and I have never got build conflicts.  A build should only use one version of Java at a time.  All versions of Java 6 are basically compatible so even if you mixed them you wouldn't see an issue.

If you tried to use a class compiled with Java 6 in a Java 5.0 compiler you would get a error which would make it obvious you have a version problem. However, if you set the '-target 1.5' option you can mix Java 5.0 and 6 compilers as well.

In short, I wouldn't worry about it unless you know you have a problem.